# How to insert data in a gridview from 2 different tables?

Tags: asp.net

if We have a Grid View with 2 Columns and In both columns i want to insert data from different tables.

(i) Can We pass 2 queries in BindGrid() ???
    Normally we write like BindGridView(sql, gv)
    (3 arguments in BindGridView)...??

(ii)  And How we can write the code for gv_RowDataBound()

Comment: I think you must visit http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36528/GridView-all-in-one to learn gridview first.

Answer (score 0):

Use **[BoundField.DataField Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.datafield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**

Your markup should look something like

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="FieldOne" HeaderText="First Field" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="FieldTwo" HeaderText="Second Field" />
      ...
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Your backend code will look something like

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("YourConnectionString"))
    {
        string sqlQuery = "select FieldOne,FieldTwo from Table1,Table2";

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                connection.Open();
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```